# `__typename` returned by the server isn't match to graphql schema

Tags: typescript, graphql, apollo-server, typegraphql, netlify-function

When I build schema using `type-graphql` and make a server with `apollo-server-lambda` and deploy it to `netlify functions`, something wrong happened.

#### schema generated by `type-graphql`

```
# -----------------------------------------------
# !!! THIS FILE WAS GENERATED BY TYPE-GRAPHQL !!!
# !!!   DO NOT MODIFY THIS FILE BY YOURSELF   !!!
# -----------------------------------------------

type Project {
  name: String!
  summary: String!
  titleAndSummary: String!
}

type Query {
  projects: [Project!]!
}
```

#### Problem

I think when I query to API

```json
{
  __schema {
    types {
      name
    }
  }
}
```

API must respond like

```
{
    "data": {
        "__schema": {
            "types": [
                {
                    "name": "Query"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Project"
                },
                // ...
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

But I got

```
{
    "data": {
        "__schema": {
            "types": [
                {
                    "name": "Query"
                },
                {
                    "name": "a"
                },
                // ...
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

I'm going to use graphql with `Elm-Graphql` what auto-generate modules using their `__typename` property. That's why I must fix the above problem.

I try hard to resolve it but even can't find where's the problem. It seems like in `type-graphql` or `apollo-server` or even `netlify functions` (I tried both netlify dev server and real server with actual deployment)

### Codes

#### graphql.ts

```js
import 'reflect-metadata';
import { ApolloServer } from 'apollo-server-lambda';
import { buildSchemaSync } from 'type-graphql';
import { QueryResolver, ProjectResolver } from './resolver';

const schema = buildSchemaSync({
  resolvers: [QueryResolver, ProjectResolver],
});

const server = new ApolloServer({
  schema,
  debug: false,
});

export const handler = server.createHandler();
```

#### types.ts

```js
import { ObjectType, Field } from 'type-graphql';

@ObjectType()
export class Query {
  @Field((type) => [Project!]!)
  projects!: Project[];
}

@ObjectType()
export class Project {
  @Field((type) => String!)
  name!: string;

  @Field((type) => String!)
  summary!: string;
}
```

#### resolver.ts

```js
import { Resolver, Query, FieldResolver, Root } from 'type-graphql';
import { Project } from './types';
import { projectList } from '../../db/fakeDB';

@Resolver()
export class QueryResolver {
  @Query((returns) => [Project])
  projects() {
    return projectList;
  }
}

@Resolver((of) => Project)
export class ProjectResolver {
  @FieldResolver((returns) => String!)
  titleAndSummary(@Root() project: Project) {
    return project.name + ' ++ ' + project.summary;
  }
}
```

### Trial

add `__typename` to Objec Type directly like below

```js
 @Resolver((of) => Project)
export class ProjectResolver {
  @FieldResolver((returns) => String!)
  titleAndSummary(@Root() project: Project) {
    return project.name + ' ++ ' + project.summary;
  }

  @FieldResolver((returns) => String!)
  __typename() {
    return 'Project';
  }
}
```

But It throws an error on the request

```
◈ Error during invocation:  {
  errorMessage: 'Name "__typename" must not begin with "__", which is reserved by GraphQL introspection.',
  errorType: 'Error',
...
```

How can I solve it?

Because I'm not good at English, I worry about If there's a wrong thing. please let me know and correct. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you have turned on bundle minification, so all the class names are mangled.

Answer (score 0):

We see this with SST and TypeGraphQL when run in production. The "__typename" attribute of ObjectType() and InputType() classes are being transformed into two letter codes. [See photo.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JfxpG.png)

Michał, can you elaborate on the bundle minification in TypeGraphQL and how it can be configured to maintain the class names of the source code ObjectType() and InputType() declarations?

```
"@serverless-stack/cli": "0.54.4",
"@serverless-stack/resources": "0.54.4",    
"apollo-server-lambda": "^2.21.1",
"type-graphql": "^1.1.1",

const server = new ApolloServer({
  schema: buildSchemaSync({
    resolvers: [getWebPaths],
    scalarsMap: [],
    validate: false,
  }),

  playground: true, //IS_LOCAL,
  introspection: true, // IS_LOCAL,

  context: async ({
    context,
    event,
  }: {
    event: APIGatewayEvent
    context: Context
  }): Promise<LambdaRoot> => {
    context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = false

    return {
      event,
      context,
    }
  },
})
```

Comment: This should be a comment on Michał's answer, not an answer in its own right.